# Azure Search: How to optimize storage?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I recently was asked to optimize costs of our Search Service instance.
First thing that I tried to think of - reduce number of partitions (we have **3** replicas and **6** partitions on Standard S2 SKU). But I was unable to do so because more than 60% of storage is already allocated and reducing number of partitions is not possible.
I've read about how Azure Search stored data under the covers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-3-document-retrieval

It says that each searchable field is presented as a reversed index.

Question: what will happen with storage allocation if I define **2** identical indexes in Azure Search? Will it "double" storage used?

I think about Azure Search index as a "container" for reversed indexes created for each searchable field. Is my statement correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, the inverted indexes are separate from one index to another, so if you create another copy index, it would basically double the storage size.

A few things you might want to look at is the following:

- Are you turning on features that you don't need?  For example are you making the field facetable and filterable when you don't actually need it to be?
- Are you using Complex Types when you could store everything at the root level of the index (or maybe make use of Collections)?
- Are there fields you are using that are not actually used for search / faceting / or filtering that you could move outside of the search index?  For example, when you click on a document, maybe the index stores a URL reference to where you can load some JSON from blob storage that has the additional metadata

Each of these can save not only space but indexing time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder, what if I merge two indexes? Will it impact performance a lot?

Comment: It will impact performance, but it is really challenging to answer the exact impact due to variations in SKU (Tier) resources, differences in schemas, workloads, etc. I will say that it is incredibly common for people to merge content into single indexes and then leverage filters to limit results that come back based on say index1 vs index2.